# SSL Certificate

Tags: wordpress, dns, google-search, https, security-certificate

I've received the email below from Google about my WordPress site and have no idea how to follow the instructions. Any help out there?

> Dear Webmaster, The host name of your site, `https://www.example.com/` does not match any of the "Subject Names" in your SSL certificate, which were:
>   *.wordpress.com
>   wordpress.com
>   This will cause many web browsers to block users from accessing your site, or to display a security warning message when your site is accessed. To correct this problem, please get a new SSL certificate from a Certificate Authority (CA) with a "Subject Name" or "Subject Alternative DNS Names" that matches your host name. Thanks, The Google Web-Crawling Team

Comment: You are using a certificate for wordpress.com, but your website is `inkwellproofreading.com`. Get a certificate for `inkwellproofreading.com`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the warning I get from Google Chrome when I try to access your website.

[image: SSL Warning]

The reason is because you are using a SSL certificate valid for wordpress.com subdomains for an HTTPS connection to a different domain. The certificate would work only if you use the original Actually URL (in your case `https://theprovenpudding.wordpress.com`).

The `https://` protocol requires a SSL certificate to encrypt the communication. Either use `http://` or buy a certificate for your domain.

Actually, I'm not sure if you can use your own certificate with the hosted version of WordPress. You should contact support to get more information.

There are a few similar discussions in the WordPress.com forums

- http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/how-do-i-obtain-an-https-certificate#post-887256
- http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/hi-need-support-for-upgraded-site-css-customization#post-898731
- http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/security-warning-message#post-889066